# PHP datetime to timestamp

Tags: php, timestamp

I want to convert my date time which is in this format

> 2015-05-11T18:30:00+05:30

and I want to convert this to timestamp.

I have tried this code

```
$time = $event->start['dateTime'];   // return 2015-05-11T18:30:00+05:30
echo  date_timestamp_get($time);
```

But getting this error

> Warning: `date_timestamp_get()` expects parameter 1 to be DateTime

How I can fix this?

Comment: *Really?* Maybe: `$time = new DateTime($event->start['dateTime']);` ?!  **expects** `parameter 1 to be` [**DateTime**](http://php.net/manual/en/class.datetime.php)

Comment: no $time = $event->start['dateTime']; is correct and print correct date time like 2015-05-11T18:30:00+05:30 
I have get this form google event calendar and know try to save Google event to my database .

Comment: (I just hope you don't troll me here).  `date_timestamp_get()` expects that the first parameter is a DateTime object. `What you have is a string` !== `DateTime object`. to now create a *new* DateTime object, just use the code above ^ instead of your current line. And then instead of `date_timestamp_get($time)` you can simply do: `$time->getTimestamp();`

Comment: Catchable fatal error: Object of class DateTime could not be converted to string this error now

Comment: Do you use OOP style to get your timestamp: `$time->getTimestamp();` ?

Comment: yes now its working thnaks

Comment: @Rizier123 dont you see he is using `date_timestamp_get()`.

Comment: @sgtBOSE I think as from OP's error he probably tried to do this: `echo $date`. which will throw this error. So if he created the DateTime object in OOP style I think it is good when he doesn't mix it with a procedural function.

Comment: I cleaned your question format up some. You might want to consider reading the [edit help](http://stackoverflow.com/editing-help) to learn how to format your questions in the future.

Comment: @Machavity I will take care next time.. Can you please vote my question if you think this is helpful for other

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First you need to create [`DateTime`](http://php.net/manual/en/class.datetime.php) object. Like this:

```
$time = new DateTime($event->start['dateTime']);
```

After this since you now use OOP style you probably also want to use OOP style to get your timestamp and so that you don't mix procedural style with OOP style, e.g.

```
$time->getTimestamp();
```

See [`getTimestamp()`](http://php.net/manual/en/datetime.gettimestamp.php) for more information and the difference about the procedural style and the OOP style.